# Using a nested "if" block to calculate windchill (python)

Tags: python, nested

*EDITTED 
Here is the entire script. I need to calculate the wind chill using air temperature (T) and wind speed (U). I have noted the block I am struggling with. When I run the program, TWC = T. In other words, it is not calculating the wind chill.

```
import sys
import cgi # to retrieve arguments from html forms
from mesohelper import getmeso # mesohelper.py needs to be in same 
directory

form = cgi.FieldStorage() #this will have the arguments sent via the 
html form
timestamp = form.getvalue('timestamp','') # '' is default, if timestamp 
does not exist  
stid = form.getvalue('stid','NRMN') # NRMN is default
station_id = stid.upper() # this changes stid to uppercase
debug = form.getvalue('debug')=='on' # more optional diaganostic 
messages

print("Content-type: text/html\n") # required for serving content as a 
web page
print("""<html>
<head>
<title>mesosite.cgi</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=300">
</head>
<body>
<pre>""") # html tags for the top of the page that your sending

if debug: print(form)

print("You requested mesonet data at time:",timestamp)
mdata,timefile = getmeso(timestamp,debug=debug) # retrieves requested 
mesonet data
print("\nretrieved file with timestamp:",timefile)
if debug: print("Here is mdata:\n",mdata)

# mdata is a dictionary, with keys that access a dictionary for the 
site
stids = mdata.keys() # a list of all the mesonet station id
# look at data for requested station_id:
if station_id not in stids:
    print(station_id,"is not a valid station id")
else: #do things with the stored data
    print("here is the data found for key:",station_id)
    sitedata = mdata[station_id] # sitedata is a dictionary within the 
    mdata dictionary
    keys = sitedata.keys() # keys for the values of the measurements 
    that are stored
    for key in sorted(keys): 
        print(' ', key, sitedata[key])
    T = sitedata['tair'] # degree C
    U = sitedata['wspd'] # in m/s
    TWC = -900 # it is designated missing, until we compute it 
    if T>-900 and U>-900:
        V = U*3.6
        # STUDENTS: Maybe four more lines to compute TWC from T and V
        # T must be less than 10 C and V greater than 4.8 km/hr, 
        otherwise TWC=T
        # You may need nested if blocks to accomplish the correct 
        assignment to TWC
#I wrote these next four lines
        if T<10 and V>4.8:
            TWC = 13.12+0.6215*T-11.37*V**0.16+0.3965*T**0.16
        else:
            TWC = T
    else:
        print("\nmissing data.. wind chill temperature not computable")

# print out computed wind chill temperature:
    if TWC != -900 :    
        print("\n  and here is the computed wind chill temperature:")
        twc_celsius_string = "%6.2f C" % TWC
        print("  TWC", twc_celsius_string)
```

The areas marked STUDENT are notes by the professor. I apparently need four lines in the "if T>-900 and U>-900" block to calculate wind chill. I thought the four lines I added would work but apparently not. Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Does it not work as you expected? What about it is not enough?

Comment: You are not asking a specific question. What is wrong with the code? Are you getting error messages? Are you failing tests? Do you have any inputs that don't give you the expected outputs? [Clarify what exactly you're asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific. The professor's notes say I need about 4 lines. When I run the program with the code as is, I don't get any output for wind chill.

Comment: There's still not enough information to help you. Your problem is with your input data and condition; clearly, the `if` statement you've written isn't getting entered, so take a look at your data and problem definition and figure out when you think it ought to be entered and what's wrong with your conditions.

Comment: Just a thought though: you never print out the computed `TWC`, so from the provided code, you wouldn't expect anything else to get printed to the screen. Should you `print(TWC)` after computing it?

Comment: scnerd sorry about that, just edited it and included the print block

Comment: can't find the block you are struggling with. however, if you're still getting `missing data.. wind chill temperature not computable` output, then the condition `if T>-900 and U>-900:` is not evaluating to `True`, thus the `else` clause outputs that message: `wind chill temperature not computable`, etc. A suggestion to track down why TWC/windchill is not getting computed, just before the line `if T>-900 and U>-900:` print out the values for variables `T` and `U` and check if they are values you expect.

Comment: davedwards when I run it as is for any time stamp, I don't get any wind chill output. It just says "and here is the computed wind chill temperature:" and nothing after that.

Comment: I am wondering if my wind chill equation is properly formatted. is the TWC = equation written properly?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In case anyone struggles with a similar problem, this is what I did:

```
if T>-900 and U>-900:
    V = U*3.6
    if T<10 and V>4.8:
        TWC = 13.12 + (0.6215*T) - 11.37*(V**0.16) + 0.3965*T*(V**0.16)   
else:
    print("\nmissing data.. wind chill temperature not computable")
```

And then I called the function

```
   if TWC != -900 :    
    print("\n  and here is the computed wind chill temperature:")
    twc_celsius_string = "%6.2f C" % TWC
```